# create json with data local

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Good morning, community, I would like you to help me with a topic that has me confused, going into context: there is a project in flutter which consumes an api that must be stored locally to avoid making requests to the webService. The serious question is how can I consume the data from my local database to create the corresponding widgets and thus create the respective forms?

I have tried to make a query for each table saved in my local database and there create a json and consume it,
however this has a disadvantage which when traversing each table takes time and in performs it is not optimal

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [Sqlfite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) you can use this site [Dart QuickType](https://dart-quicktype.netlify.app/) to generate your models to import your tables from the local storage, I suggest make a single class handling the DB access, and then as many as you need (models and DAOs in where you write your queries) according to your DB arch.
You can consume later your info using FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder if you're using BLoC architecture or another DB management package like [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift)